# Encoding on turbo c editor

Tags: c, encoding, turbo-c

I wrote a code on my text editor, and the Turbo C editor does not return the enter character!

[image]

**How to convert the text encoding?**

Comment: Paste the original code here..

Comment: The code is big too much!

Comment: I downloaded the code at https://kernel.org and im running on the MS-DOS's Turbo C

Comment: That is what the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is for. Please set up a short example code that shows the problem.

Comment: how can a Linux kernel be compiled with Turbo C?

Comment: Heh, i do no... i have only a msdos, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Turbo C version which I were using does not have full encoding support (which nowdays is not a problem). Hovewer, the latest Turbo C version will add some extra support.

As many guys have said years ago, I should not be using Turbo C. **If you want to write C code in Android, use [Termux](https://termux.dev/)** with gcc

Comment: Note that Turbo C is an outdated compiler that you probably should not be using. Use a modern compiler like gcc or clang.

Comment: Djgcc is a gcc somewhat less older than turbo c, ported to ms-dos. It does need a 386 (or better) to run. But if your computer was made after the early ninetees, that should not be a problem. On the other hand, if your computer is not a 8088 or a 286, you can probably install a modern OS that supports gcc

Comment: you should not use DOS either

Comment: Thanks, i don't have pc, but i have an emulator